# Image not displaying on Firefox (bootstrap + Wordpress) due to AdBlock issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this code using Wordpress + Bootstrap, and somehow images aren't showing in Firefox, however, they display correctly in any other browser. I did a search at SO and found some answers related to disabling ad-block, but it didn't solve the issue, so I'm quite lost here.

The relevant HTML part

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-12 active"><a title="Home" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a title="Carriers" href="/our-carriers/">Carriers</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a title="Our Story" href="/our-story/">Our Story</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-121"><a title="Employees" href="/employees/">Employees</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a title="Contact Us" href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <div class="col-fb">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxx">
          <img class="like_us" src="xxxxx/wp-content/themes/xxx_Theme/images/fb_like.png" alt="Like AIG on Facebook" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS. I've added the last 2 lines in an attempt to "force" display, but nothing happened, exception made that the elements now have width and height, which they didn't have before I have added those lines:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  line-height: 1px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 3px 15px
}
#nav,
.navbar {
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.nav-header ul {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: #3f4646;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  padding: 0 !important;
  background: #7f8c8d;
  z-index: 100000000 !important;
}
li.active a {
  background: transparent !important;
}
ul.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px
}
.navbar li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
.navbar li a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
  color: #2c3e50 !important
}
.navbar .container {
  max-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  top: 0px !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000000 !important;
  border: none
}
.nav-header ul {
  padding: 10px;
}
.nav-header ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 10px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 10px
}
.col-fb a,
.col-fb {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000
}
.col-fb img {
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000100;
  height: auto;
}
```

As additional info, while you may see the image has a `fb_like` class, when I check Firefox inspector it has a random class added: `cprflzcqqyowaemjgtdl`

Any idea on what am I doing wrong or how to fix this?

**EDIT: It actually is an AdBlock issue, so I'd need to know how to override that issue, since I can disable it, but of course I need to allow this for everybody**

Comment: I replaced the domain name with xxxxx, but the real one is obviously correct or it wouldn't show in every browser. Either way, it actually is an Ad-Block issue, when I disabled it at first, it didn't really disabled, on a second try I see it works when I disable Ad Block. Now trying to figure how to overcome that

Comment: Sorry, but how do you know I'm not linking to an inner folder structure, which doesn't need a protocol? And really, how does this help at all with the issue? It's totally and absolutely unrelated

Comment: yes. And as I said, it shows in every browser, and if I disable AdBlock it shows up in Firefox as well, so it's 100% an AdBlock issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

I went replacing every single thing related to Facebook, starting by the link, which I replaced with a **bit.ly** redirection, but it wasn't enough. Then replaced the `alt`, still didn't work. Changed all occurences of `fb*` to `fk*` and bam!, **AdBlock** didn't catch it and now the image shows up as intended. Just for reference, here's the code for anyone having this issue, with WP Nav Walker and Bootstrap code:

```html
<?php
 $fblike = get_template_directory_uri();
 wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu'              => 'primary',
  'depth'             => 2,
  'container'         => 'div',
  'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse ',
  'items_wrap'   => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">%3$s<li class="menu-item"><div class="col-fk"><a href="http://on.fb.me/xxxxxx"><img class="like_us" src="'.$fblike.'/images/fk_like.png" alt="" /></a></div></li></ul>',
  'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
  'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
 );
?>
```

Seems stupid, and probably is. But it works, so hope it helps to anyone looking for the answer to this issue